# RsaSecurityKey does not take RSAParameters as arguments

Tags: c#, .net, jwt, encryption-asymmetric

I want to generate a JWT Token in .Net 4.5 using an asymmetric key that I provide myself, but I am running into a few issues with the System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt, version 4.0.3.

Preferably I would create my own 2048 keys, like provider allows me to do.  The RSA.Create() constructor creates 1024 keys.

```
using (RSACryptoServiceProvider provider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048))
        {
            var publicPrivate = provider.ToXmlString(true);
            var publicKeyOnly = provider.ToXmlString(false);

            var stuff = provider.ExportParameters(true);

            signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new RsaSecurityKey(RSA.Create()), SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256Signature, SecurityAlgorithms.Sha256Digest); //no idea how to pull the key out of here.

        }
```

In many examples one can drop RSAParameters into the RsaSecurityKey constructor, but now it only takes the RSA.Create() constructor (with optional string parameter)  The following code snip comes from https://stackoverflow.com/a/38233644 Note that in this example the RSAParameters go nicely into the RsaSecurityKey constructor, which I cannot do with my version, I am restricted to using RSA.Create, it seams.

```
// NOTE: Replace this with your actual RSA public/private keypair!
var provider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);
var parameters = provider.ExportParameters(true);

// Build the credentials used to sign the JWT
var signingKey = new RsaSecurityKey(parameters);  //not an option for me, unfortunately
```

Comment: One element of this is that for 4.0.3 one doesn't use the parameters in the RsaSecurityKey, you use the provider.  

     var provider = new RSACryptoService(2048);
     var signingKey = new RsaSecurityKey(provider);

I found it in the following link.
https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/issues/477

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I did.  First I ran the debugger and the first time through I capture the XML from my new provider using the ToXmlString(Boolean) method of the new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048).  Then I made that an XML file for storage.  (In this example I just use my hard drive for storage, obviously not production code.)

Now that I have the RSAPrameters, I have the key "that I provide myself", it could come from any secure storage - doesn't matter for this answer.

```
XmlDocument publicXmlParam = new XmlDocument();
publicXmlParam.Load("C:\\rsapublicprivate.xml");

// Here I "utilize my own 2048 keys"
RSACryptoServiceProvider provider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);

//This was the trick, we pass the RSA parameters as XML into the provider.           
provider.FromXmlString(publicXmlParam.OuterXml); 

// Then we use the provider in the constructor of the RsaSecurityKey
var key = new RsaSecurityKey(provider); 

signingCredentials = 
    new SigningCredentials(
        key, 
        SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256Signature,   
        SecurityAlgorithms.Sha256Digest);
```

Now I have the signing credentials that I need to sign my JWT Token.