# Initializing RSA from String

Tags: c#, rsa

I am trying to decrypt some text that is encrypted with RSA, I have the public key to do this

`

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGWAoGBAMqfGO9sPz+kxaRh/qVKsZQGul7NdG1gonSS3KPXTjtcHTFfexA4MkGA
mwKeu9XeTRFgMMxX99WmyaFvNzuxSlCFI/foCkx0TZCFZjpKFHLXryxWrkG1Bl9+
+gKTvTJ4rWk1RvnxYhm3n/Rxo2NoJM/822Oo7YBZ5rmk8NuJU4HLAhAYcJLaZFTO
sYU+aRX4RmoF
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

`

How can I load this into `RSACryptoServiceProvider` because this can only load from XMLString and I do not know how to convert this to Xml format

The key size is 128

I tried to initialize it using the following code

```
public byte[] Decrypt128(byte[] input)
{
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(128);
    rsa.ImportCspBlob(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_longKey));
    return rsa.Decrypt(input, true);
}
```

_longKey is the content between BEGIN and END and also including the BEGIN and END, bot `Bad Version of provider.`

This is not a duplicate question of [How do you convert Byte Array to Hexadecimal String, and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa)

I already know how to convert byte to hex and hex to byte, but that in any way does not help me initializing `RSACryptoServiceProvider` maybe give me example how that would help but at this point it doesn't

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you convert Byte Array to Hexadecimal String, and vice versa?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa)

Comment: I am not sure how this is a possible duplicate if I need to initialize `RSACryptoServiceProvider` using the public key

Comment: The contents between BEGIN and END are likely a hexademical string, or even more likely a [Base64](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134837/how-do-i-decode-a-base64-encoded-string) one. So Encoding.GetBytes won't work.

Comment: According to the [MSDN Documentation on the `RSACryptoServiceProvider.ImportCspBlob`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.importcspblob(v=vs.110).aspx), there is no mention of anything requiring XML of any description.

Comment: I am going to give that a try, but it is definitely not a duplicate of that question

Comment: @Abion47 I know, but the XML I am talking about was `FromXmlString` which I tried, I then moved to `ImportCspBlob in the last 10 minutes to try something else

Comment: And [ImportCspBlob](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.importcspblob(v=vs.110).aspx) has nothing to do with public key bytes. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654400/rsacryptoserviceprovider-initialize-with-own-public-key-and-private-key for some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`BouncyCastle`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BouncyCastle/) which has a `PemReader` allowing you to extract the modulus and exponent for the key:

```
using (var reader = File.OpenText("mykey.key"))
{
    var pem = new PemReader(reader);
    var o = (RsaKeyParameters)pem.ReadObject();
    using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        var parameters = new RSAParameters();
        parameters.Modulus = o.Modulus.ToByteArray();
        parameters.Exponent = o.Exponent.ToByteArray();
        rsa.ImportParameters(parameters);

        // Do what you need to do with the RSACryptoServiceProvider instance
    }
}
```

If you don't want to have a dependency on BouncyCastle in your project, once loaded the public key into the `RSACryptoServiceProvider` using this method you could export it to XML for future use:

```
string xml = rsa.ToXmlString(false);
File.WriteAllText("mykey.xml", xml);
```

Comment: I think this might just work, I updated my question with the public key, I think it may be broken or something it loads perfectly but ImportParameters gives `Bad Data`

Comment: I cannot see the actual public key which is causing Bad Data in your question.

Comment: The Exponent of this public key is 16 bytes which greatly exceeds the 4 bytes that the `RSACryptoServiceProvider` supports.

Comment: Yikes, any suggestions ?

Comment: You will need another private/public key pair in which the exponent of the public key doesn't exceed 4 bytes.

Comment: Ish that is not possible but thanks for your help, will accept your answer this public key exists already for a long time

Comment: While `RSACryptoServiceProvider` is limited to a 4 byte exponent value, `RSACng` doesn't have that limit.  It *should* work with pretty much any exponent (in excess of a 16k-bit exponent might be pushing it, though).

Comment: Very good point about the `RSACng` class. Unfortunately it is available from .NET 4.6, but if this is not a problem then it could be a great alternative.