# Google SDK Token from private key file

Tags: powershell, google-admin-sdk

I'm writing a PowerShell script to interact with our Chromebook inventory and I have followed the process outlined here

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation

To create a private key file and delegated it permissions.

However, there's no documentation how to decode the public/private key to generate a token without using one of the pre-built libraries, which of course don't include PowerShell. Even if there was a language agnostic description of what needs to be done I'd be able to try something out, but unfortunately there isn't.

I found this question which seems to be the same issue as what I'm having but it was never answered either.

[Google Identity Platform: Using OAuth 2.0 in Powershell using Firebase Admin SDK private key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51832533/google-identity-platform-using-oauth-2-0-in-powershell-using-firebase-admin-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a pfx rather than the JSON file and following the [framework laid out here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50265150/accessing-g-suite-admin-sdk-using-service-account). Your scopes will be different but this should get you started.