# RSA Encryption/Decryption Algorithm with custom keys

Tags: c#, asp.net, cryptography, rsa

I want to use RSA Algorithm to encrypt/decrypt texts in my ASP.NET application. But I want to encrypt text on another application using private key and decrypt the text on the primary application using the public key.

But as I see, the algorithm's implementation in ASP.NET uses own key generation and I can't use custom key pairs.

May you please help me how can I use my own public/private key pairs in RSA implementation in ASP.NET?

Thank you

Comment: Question is already replied here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654400/rsacryptoserviceprovider-initialize-with-own-public-key-and-private-key

Comment: Arendt there import and export functions ? I can't believe...

Comment: You cannot **encrypt with a private key**, period. Especially with common RSA keys, once you know the private key you also know the public key, for one. They cannot be used interchangeably.

Comment: What have you tried? what doesn't work?